# LibGDX facebook login integration

Tags: java, android, facebook, libgdx

Hello I am creating some cards game online using LibGDX, and I want to connect my app using facebook so they can invite friends to join the game room. I want to make people to connect without having facebook too.

The game should not have authentication besides facebook, users without facebook just enter their nickname and they will have user-id that can be used to get invited.

My question is, what would be the best way to integrate it so this can be done in both ways?

What if friends in facebook doesn't have that application? Is there a way to detect friends that have that app? Or a way to invite them to download this app and connect?

And how does facebook integration work for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, what would be the best way to integrate it so this can
>   be done in both ways?

First of all you need some kind of server which handles all the user accounts/nicknames/login/logout etc. 
After this works you can add Facebook integration. Since Facebook provides an unique id for each user you just have to link this id to a normal user account on your server. So the user has two ways to login: A) normal login (just nickname) and B) Facebook, which redirects login to the linked normal account.

Advantage: You can add other login options (Google+, Twitter, ...) later on easily. Just link to the normal account.

> What if friends in facebook doesn't have that application?

Does not matter, since your server does not know whether somebody has logged in from facebook or normal way. He just matches the logged in players and good to go.

> Is there a way to detect friends that have that app?

I do not know if there is currently a solution for that. Due to privacy regulations this will change from time to time.

> Or a way to invite them to download this app and connect?

Facebook SDK allows you to open friend invite dialog. You can customize as well. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites

> And how does Facebook integration work for my case?

As said above: Server, login normal, link facebook logins.

If you want to use Facebook to handle game related stuff then there is now way to play your game without Facebook.